# Объединить две выборки есть Select

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста объединить две выборки есть Select постов выглядит она так.

```
<?php
$post_query= mysql_query("SELECT u.id,p.*,u.username,u.family,u.avatar,u.lastdate
FROM post p, users u
WHERE CASE
WHEN p.user1 = '$myrow[id]'
THEN p.user2 = u.id
WHEN u.id = '$user2'
THEN p.user1= u.id
END
AND (
p.user1 ='$myrow[id]'
OR p.user2 ='$myrow[id]'
)
Order by p.ps_id DESC Limit 20") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

И комментариев к этим постам.

```
<?php
$comment_query = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.* FROM comment a, users b
WHERE a.user_from='".$user_from["id"]."' OR a.post_id='".$post_id."'
AND a.user_from=b.id
ORDER by a.date_com ASC, a.time_com ASC limit 4");
?>
```

Помогите их соединить, а то когда записей 10 на localhost начинает прям притормаживать страница.

Comment: Не думаю что вы ускорите если ещё join сделаете)

Comment: @dimka3210 Почему?

Comment: тут надо не соединять, а все стереть и написать правильно.  

1. убрать из всех запросов звездочки. и никогда их больше не использовать.
2. перестать писать from table1, table2, table3 и связь через where. использовать join'ы.
3. избавиться от or. это основная причина тормозов, т.к. индексы, какие бы вы ни создали использоваться не будут.
4. перестать писать в вопросе текст запроса в кавычках. тут отвечают люди, а не php интерпретаторы. 
5. к тому же вопрос к php отношения не имеет - это по поводу меток.
6. выяснить для себя что же вы хотите получить на выходе и зачем это нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

> `SELECT u.id,p.*,u.username,u.family,u.avatar,u.lastdate, a.*
> FROM post p 
> join users u on (CASE 
> WHEN p.user1 = '$myrow[id]'
> THEN p.user2 = u.id
> WHEN u.id = '$user2'
> THEN p.user1= u.id
> END)
> left join comment a on (a.post_id = p.post_id and a.user_from = u.user_id)
> WHERE 
> (
> p.user1 ='$myrow[id]'
> OR p.user2 ='$myrow[id]'
> )
> Order by p.ps_id DESC Limit 20`